# Play Framework 1.2.5 - adding to <script> tag

Tags: templates, playframework

In my play framework app, I have a main.html, which at the very bottom includes this javascript tag:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // add js here
        #{scripts /}
    });
</script>
```

Now I would like to be able to add arbitrary javascript from other templates, which is then collected and added to the function body, so for example in view1.html, I'd like to add the function `doCharts()` to be called on jQuery's DOMReady:

```
#{append: 'scripts'}
     doCharts();
#{/append}
```

This should then produce this output:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        // add js here
        doCharts();
    });
</script>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible

In your main file, after your script tag put

```
#{get 'moreScripts' /}
```

and in your other html files use

```
#{set 'moreScripts'}
<script type="text/javascript">
  // put your script here
</script>
#{/set}
```

if you want to put another script in the same page you can put a get into the set like this

```
#{set 'moreScripts'}
#{get 'moreScripts' /}
<script type="text/javascript">
  // put your script here
</script>
#{/set}
```

Comment: But that's setting only one variable, right? I'd like to add to that same variable multiple times.

Comment: in each page you want to add some javascript you put the set tag. If you want to put multiple set in one page, you have to put a get into the other set